# Windows C++: Prioritizing threads to prevent main thread being preempted

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio

Is there a way to communicate to Window's task scheduler that my worker threads are less urgent than my main thread, so that it might choose to interrupt them first?  I am running into some trouble with my main thread getting preempted frequently, which slows it's ability to delegate tasks out to other threads.

Comment: If your thread is frequently preempted to the point that it interferes with it's functionality, preventing the start of new tasks may be desirable.

Comment: [These](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) are all of the standard threading functionalities. There doesn't seem to be a way of adjusting priority. You'll have to rely on your platform's API.

Comment: For setting thread priority, on Windows, this might be related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf325bd2-f52b-484f-ba40-75d50e26bfc2/how-to-set-thread-priorty-using-new-stdthread?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Ah, I put `yield()` in some key spots and it had a very positive effect, there's now nearly no preemption to speak of.

Comment: How do you know that your main thread is preempted frequently ?

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar - visual studio has a thread visualization that measures preemption and synchronization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`SetThreadPriority()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority) function in the Win32 API.